# Why source-code is larger than application?

Tags: java, android

I came to know about an Android application that its source-code is having around 18 MB and actual application consist 2.8 MB. Why does this happen?

Comment: In general: Humans need more verbose syntax and comments which isn't present in compiled form. Yor your case this seems to be too specific.

Comment: I couldn't get you...Can you explain?

Comment: Besides the typical answers mentioned below related to building: zipalign and proguard are additional tools for making apk's smaller

Comment: If your variable names are usually long, you can have quite the large source-code, while these names disappear in compiled code, and thus less space is needed. (Well in most languages they do)

Answer (score 4):

Java code is translated to byte code that is much less verbose. For example

```
int httpServerPortToUse = 58000; // (32 bytes of source code)
```

is translated to the following byte code

```
iconst_58000 // (1 byte for opcode + 4 bytes for integer = 5 bytes)
```

In this example java byte code is more than 6 times smaller than java source code.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers cut out a lot of data/visual representations of code that are required for us to read it. See [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html) write-up for how Android compiles its code.

Fun fact: did you know [Rollercoaster Tycoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RollerCoaster_Tycoon_(video_game)#Development) was written entirely in Assembly code?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already posted answers, every space, tab, newline, and comment takes up space in the source code. All of this is removed by the compiler since it is all useless to the functionality.

Also, .apk files are a type of zip archive file, thus they are compressed on top of the compiler removing data. [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29)

Answer (score 0):

It's is an interesting fact you have mentioned.

I have always found uncompiled source codes to be smaller that the output application file.

However it may not be always true as in your case. A compiler may optimize and minimize the Sourcecode before compilation.

One may write

souce_code_1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
      printf("Hello World");
      return(0);
    }
```

souce_code_2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
      printf













      ("Hello World");
      return(0);
    }
```

Here, the souce_code_2.c will be definitely be larger than that of souce_code_1.c
However if you compile both of them and check you will notice that the executable full is almost of the same size.

Why does this happpen?

**Tough souce_code_1.c and souce_code_2.c produce the same output, souce_code_2.c has many elements that don't really contribute to the output of the code. the compiler gets rid of all such elements.**

That was a very simple example but there's much more to it.
If you are interested in how executables are compiled from a source you may read [Principles of Compiler Design](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Principles_of_Compiler_Design.html?id=25FQAAAAMAAJ)

Comment: Thanks to all for helping.... I am clear now